# How can I make it where it will print the longest name/string that was input by the user that doesnt need to be input again

Tags: python, list, function

```
def myNames():
    names = []
    while True:
        a = input("Enter Name: ")
        if a != "done":
            names.append(a)
        elif a == "done":
            return names

def all_lengths(myNames):
  num_of_strings = len(myNames)
  total_size = 0
  for item in myNames:
     total_size += len(item)
  ave_size = float(total_size) / float(num_of_strings)
  print(ave_size)

all_lengths(myNames())

def longestWord(myNames): 
    count = 0
    for i in myNames:
        if len(i) > count: 
            count = len(i)
            word = I
            print ("the longest string is ", word)
```

how can I make it print the longest name that was input by the user for example: out of Samantha and John it would say that Samantha was the longest name. I need it to count the longest name and display it from the first function without it making me enter names again

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to store variables. In fact, you're doing it a whole bunch in your functions already.

Another point that beginners often miss is that `def` statements don't run any code. They create functions, which just sit there until you call them or use the same name for something else.

The line you need to change that's currently calling your functions is

```
all_lengths(myNames())
```

Instead of nesting the calls, store the result:

```
names = myNames()
all_lengths(names)
```

Now you can also call

```
longestWord(names)
```

**Notes**

It's a good learning experience to implement these functions by hand. Here are some comments on how to improve your code:

- Python users conventionally use CamelCase for class names only. Functions and variables are written in snake_case. So `my_names` rather than `myNames` and `longest_word` rather than `longestWord`.
- The division operator `/` automatically returns a `float`, even when the inputs are `int`s as of python 3. No need to convert in `total_size / num_of_strings`. If you want integer truncation, you have to ask for it explicitly with the `//` floor divide operator.
- Use the `sum` built-in when you're computing sums over a sequence, even if the attribute you're summing is indirect:

  ```
    def all_lengths(my_names):
        return sum(len(x) for x in my_names) / len(my_names)
  ```
- As shown in the sample above, functions should do a single thing and generally return a value. Computing averages and printing are two things, so do the printing elsewhere.
- The `max` built-in has a `key` keyword that lets you replace `longest_name` with

  ```
    def longest_name(names):
        return max(names, key=len)
  ```

Comment: how would I put that in the code? and how do I make it print

Comment: @Kian. I'd use copy and paste. Make it print using `print`

Comment: @Kian. What are you testing exactly? Remember, I can only see what you show me, and I'm not magic.

Comment: I know but when I test the entire code it only gives the output of the average length in numbers and doesn't print the longest name

Answer (score 0):

You should try to be more precise on what actually you want to ask and then reframe it so that it would be easier for everyone to understand.

If you want to check which string is longest from list, you can simply do it like this:

```
l = ["Samantha", "John"]
maxlen = 0
maxstring = ""

for x in l:
    if len(x) > maxlen:
        maxlen = len(x)
        maxstring = x

print(maxstring)
```